# error TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined ngxs logout

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

From the auth.state I am calling logout method. I get error of:

> error TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

```js
@Action(Logout)
logout(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
  return this.loginService.logout().pipe(
    tap((result) => {
    const state = ctx.getState();
      ctx.setState({...state,
          loggedInUser:undefined,
          accessToken: undefined,
          username: undefined,
          email:undefined,
          roles:undefined,
        });
     })
  );
}
```

This is the `logOut` method

```js
public logout(): Observable<void> {
   return this.tokenStorage.signOut();
}
```

This is the `signOut` method from `localstorage`

```js
public signOut():any {
   return window.sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

Error Image:

[image]

Comment: Why did you set the return type as any for signOut()?  window.sessionStorage.clear() returns void, not an Observable.  Have that return an observable, or just get the unnecessary observable stream out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `window.sessionStorage.clear()` has a return value?

clear() is a void method that's the reason you get that error.

you can simply check a similar issue in the future by using `console.log(window.sessionStorage.clear())` then you will get if it returns value or undefined.

Comment: when i have void these methods i get  i get  Error: src/app/pages/login/state/auth.state.ts:74:37 - error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Action(Logout)
logout(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
 this.loginService.logout()
    const state = ctx.getState();
      ctx.setState({...state,
          loggedInUser:undefined,
          accessToken: undefined,
          username: undefined,
          email:undefined,
          roles:undefined,
        });
        return state;
 };
```

I replaced code with this...Thx for help... i should have asked another question that this above..problem was actualy (property pipe does not exist on type void) but i got abit lost in code ... :)